# C enum size mismatch between platform potentially dangerous

Tags: c, gcc, enums, arm, sizeof

I'm porting net-snmp to an ARM platform (ThreadX OS, not linux) starting from a working compilation on a Linux x86 machine

Right now the program crashes inside the init_snmp() function because at some point something terrible happens with the memory.

I then confronted the sizeof() all data types and found that enum is 4 bytes on Linux x86 and 1 byte on ARM.

Is it possible that such mismatch wreaks havoc with memory allocation? The program crashes while trying to write strings into the memory.

How do I force the enum to be 4 bytes large on ARM too?

I'm compiling with gcc arm-none-eabi

Comment: It really depends on the code. If this difference of size break the code: get rid of it....

Comment: Depending on some assumption of the size of enums sounds like an awful idea and something you should fix in your code. As for how to assure that your enum types will be (at least) 32 bits, how about adding another element to all of them with the value 0x12345678 (or some other value larger than 16 bits)?

Comment: It's not "my" code, it's something that a large group of people have been developing for the last 20 years :) Therefore the less I touch it, the better! I was wondering if there's some compilation flag or typedef hack to make the enums the same size as the working x86 environment. Or if the issue is relevant at all, for all I know it could be a false problem and I'm barking at the wrong tree

Comment: You need to provide sample code.  If you are relying on specific sizes for your program to work, then yes, it may cause problems.

Comment: From ISO/IEC 9899:2011: _Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, a signed integer type, or an
unsigned integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined, but shall be
capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration_

Comment: It is highly speculative that the difference in (some specific) enum size is responsible for your problem.  Have you found any code in the project that actually produces meaningfully different results depending on the size of an enum type?

Comment: Note, too, that your claims that "enum is 4 bytes on Linux x86 and 1 byte on ARM" are bogus.  The size may be different for the same enum in different compilers for the same OS and arch, and it may be different for different enums with the same compiler on the same OS and arch.  Enum size is not a characteristic of OS or architecture.

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to look because you can't just `sizeof(enum)` , you should put the name of an enum variable inside the parentheses and there are almost a thousand of `sizeof(` in the code

Two things:
1) If I make the enum start from a very large number instead of 0, its size (on ARM) becomes larger than 1
2) If I compile with the `-fshort-enums` flag on linux, the enum becomes 1 in size... but I'm not using `-fshort-enums` on ARM, there is probably some other optimization that causes the same behavior

Comment: @mfloris From the gcc manual, section on implementation-defined behavior: *Normally, the type is 'unsigned int' if there are no negative
     values in the enumeration, otherwise 'int'.  If '-fshort-enums' is
     specified, then if there are negative values it is the first of
     'signed char', 'short' and 'int' that can represent all the values,
     otherwise it is the first of 'unsigned char', 'unsigned short' and
     'unsigned int' that can represent all the values.

     On some targets, '-fshort-enums' is the default; this is determined
     by the ABI.*

Comment: @JohnBollinger I should have specified that I'm compiling the same source in the two platforms. The difference is relative to the minimum size of the enum in this case. Linux is using the standard way i.e. the same size of an unsigned int, ARM compiler is configured to use the minimum size

Comment: @mfloris: that you are building the same source on both platforms has no bearing whatever on my previous comments.  Indeed, that's what I had assumed you were doing.

Comment: @mflores: you observe that "If I compile with the -fshort-enums flag on linux, the enum becomes 1 in size."  Does the package still work in that case?  If so, it seems that would undercut your hypothesis that the difference in enum size is responsible for the failure on ARM.

Comment: As John points out, the discrepancy is not between ARM and x86, but between a toolchain built for Linux and a toolchain built for bare-metal microcontrollers (with the default behaviours that brings). `-fno-short-enums` should make a codebase that (incorrectly) assumes enum size to be `sizeof(int)` to compile correctly. In that regard.You may then instead trip over other incorrect assumptions.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, trying short enums on linux to see if it breaks the code is next on the list

Comment: @unixsmurf I tried -fno-short-enums and albeit enums are now minimum 4 bytes in size, the actual code doesn't start at all (I won't bother debugging)

I guess I'll have to spend some quality time with the debugger to find out when and where the memory gets corrupted, and why... thank you all anyway for your support

Comment: @JohnBollinger: The size of an enumerated constant must be specified by the platform ABI precisely in order to allow interoperability of code compiled with different compilers. If it were the case that "the size may be different for the same enum in different compilers for the same OS and arch", then interop would be impossible. OTOH, it is completely true that the size may vary for different enumerations. Options like `-fshort-enums` need to be accompanied with warnings that they will break ABI compatibility (and afaik the gcc docs do so).

Comment: @mfloris: ... and as I just wrote to JohnBollinger, you cannot expect to change a compiler setting related to enum sizes and still have your code work if it uses any enumeration declared in a standard library header. (Or, indeed, any other external library.) So it's not that surprising that your code doesn't work when compiled with `-fno-short-enums`.

Comment: @rici, indeed, interop is possible only to the extent that implementations cooperate to make it so.  Nothing in C requires interoperability between implementations.  The fact that different implementations (or even *the same* implementation under different conditions) can choose different sizes for the same enum type is but one of many interoperability challenges.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: But they cannot choose different sizes *if they conform to the platform ABI*. And the platform ABI is in fact an applicable formal standard which compilers conform to (unless explicitly instructed not to by a kamikaze user).

Comment: I ran some better tests and I can tell that compiling the code with short-enums (default) or -fno-short-enums makes no difference at all, it crashes the same way. Besides there only is a difference when enums start at 0 (or any small number), otherwise if a big number is stored inside both options yield the same result. I'm talking about the actual net-snmp code. The test program that only prints the sizeof()s works fine in both cases. There is also a discrepancy on "long double" , 8B on arm and 12B on pc.  Maybe that's where I have to look

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible that such mismatch wreaks havoc with memory allocation?

Oh yes.

> How do I force the enum to be 4 bytes large on ARM too?

The C standard says that an enum variable may have any pretty much any integer type, the size and signedness is implementation-defined. enum is generally problematic to use for this reason, particularly in embedded systems. This is a known flaw of the C language.

It is possible that you can force enum to be of a specific size for a specific compiler, but that is just a quick & dirty fix.

The professional, long-term solution is to rewrite all code so that there are no reliance of the size or signedness of enum anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to overcome the boundaries of the compiler. This example provides a way to change the size of the `enum` when needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum small_enum {
    a 
};

enum large_enum {
    b = 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF // 2^63-1, you should try 2^31-1
};

int main(){
    printf("%d %d\n", sizeof(enum small_enum), sizeof(enum large_enum));
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives the following output: `4 8` when run on an Windows 8 machine. By specifying a big number to one of the enums values you are forcing the enum to be bigger than the compiler defines. Example of adding this to your code:

```
enum my_enum {
    ... //your enums values
    MEM_ALLIGNMENT_OF_THE_ENUM = 0x7FFFFFFF
};
```

Comment: While the enum variable may have any size, the enumeration constant `b` can only be of type `int`. Thus `0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` will get truncated. So I'm not certain how reliable this trick would be in practice. Anyway, adding an icky 0x7FF... member to every enum in the program doesn't exactly sound like a smooth fix.